# Highlighting specific words in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, highlight

To sumarize the most of it, i'm trying to create an sheet to emulate an RPG game inventory. The problem i'm stuck at is "item rarity grading coloring". So the "common" item will be gray, the "rare" will be blue, the "ancient" will be red, and this is measured by "stars".

The inventory cell that is a input, the player will go: "Blades of ancient times - 5*" or "Daggers of Bleeding [5*]" (without quotes)

I came up with this:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  if (ss.getName() !== "z") return; // Get out quickly
  var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var changedCellA1 = changedCell.getA1Notation();

  var c = event.value;  // We know we edited cell, just get the value
  var background = 'gray'; // Assume 1 <= c <= 2
  if (c == 2) {
    background = 'red';
  }
  else if (c == 1) {
    background = 'white'; 
  }
  changedCell.setFontColor(background);
}
```

But when it hits the "if (c == 2)" i just don't know how to properly get the info in the script from what i need...

```
if (c has or ends with "[1*]") do white text
if (c has or ends with "[2*]") do grey text
```

In this, if you're on the "z" sheet and edit a cell, if its 1 will be white, if its 2 will be red.

Comment: You might be able to do that with richtext I don't really know because I've only used it a couple of times.  I normally don't care about such things.

Answer (score 1):

### SOLUTION

- You can use [***`includes()`***](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method on your if-else statement. You can try this edited sample script below:

### Sample Script

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  if (ss.getName() !== "z") return; // Get out quickly
  var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var changedCellA1 = changedCell.getA1Notation();

  var c = event.value;  // We know we edited cell, just get the value
  var background = 'gray'; // Assume 1 <= c <= 2
  if (c.includes("2")) {
    background = 'red';
  }
  else if (c.includes("1")) {
    background = 'white'; 
  }
  changedCell.setFontColor(background);
}
```

### Test Demonstration

> Test Sheet *(changed background to color black for text color change visibility)*

[image]

> When the value in A1 gets edited/updated:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh thank! But i ended up going with "EndsWith".